# Long time duration to import a CSV File into Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I want to Import a small csv file (400KO) about 5000 lines in Neo4J using LOAD CSV but the duration time is more than 5 minutes
Here is the command i used. 
First to avoid the eager i use to merge the nodes in the file

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV with headers from "file:///CDR/file_5min.csv" as ligne
WITH ligne LIMIT 0
MERGE (p:Person {Tel:ligne.CALLER_MSISDN})
MERGE (d:Person {Tel:ligne.CALLED_NUMBER})
```

After that i merge the relationship between those nodes

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV with headers from "file:///CDR/file_5min.csv" as ligne
WITH ligne LIMIT 0
MATCH (p:Person {Tel:ligne.CALLER_MSISDN})
MATCH (d:Person {Tel:ligne.CALLED_NUMBER})
MERGE result = (p)-[c:CALL]->(d)
ON CREATE SET c.Loc = ligne.CALLER_CELL_ID, c.Start = ligne.START_TIME
ON MATCH SET c.Loc = ligne.CALLER_CELL_ID, c.Start = ligne.START_TIME
```

When using PROFILE i don't find the eager so i want to know what is the problem.

Comment: What about index?

Comment: I have put an index on "Tel"